# Has anyone unit tested a HttpModule in ASP.NET using rhino Mocks framework?

Tags: unit-testing, rhino-mocks, httpmodule

If so, can you please supply a sample test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help:

http://weblogs.asp.net/rashid/archive/2009/03/12/unit-testable-httpmodule-and-httphandler.aspx

Comment: seen that article but I have a more complex scenario to test so its unsuitable